# httpS pages crawled while never bought SSL Certificate

Tags: https, http

I have a website built in WP. I never bought any ssl certificate for my website, nor a single link pointing to httpS, however, 02 of the pages are crawled with httpS, while rest pages are with http. While Google crawled with httpS. And now when someone is landing to this page using serp, it's showing an error message.

I talked to the hosting company, initially they said that the free ssl was issued to your website (which i never requested), but when i created an ticket, the support team is now telling that its search engine issue, we can't do anything.

Shall i redirect the 02 pages from https to http  ?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking here (e.g., what does "02" mean, do you still have a free SSL certificate, and why would there be an error if so?). We also generally don't do individual SEO or website troubleshooting here. Google has started to prioritize URLs using HTTPS and [Chrome](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-is-requiring-https-for-secure-data-in-chrome/183756/) now requires it, so you'd do better to get a certificate if you don't already have one and redirect all your HTTP pages to HTTPS using a `301`, rather than going  backwards.

Comment: @dan - 02 means - two pages, out of  21 pages of my website, only 02 pages crawled with httpS, while rest are fine. I didn't purchased ssl, nor any internal link pointing to httpS. I am scratching my head to know how come httpS crawled. I understand, individual site are not troubleshoot, but many other people are facing exactly same issue. I have been going through several sites including webmaster and other sites, and many users are facing similar issues.

Comment: Now the main issue is, the https version is ranking, which showing an error message ''your connection is not secure'' - please see the printscreen here https://image.ibb.co/mSh37R/ssl_error.png

Comment: As to _how_ it happened, there's no way for us to know. You can request that Google remove the URLs with HTTPS using Google Search Console. However, your users are still going to keep getting SSL errors since Chrome is now requiring certificates (see the above link), and it may take time for the Google to remove them. You're better off moving forward at this point since you only have 21 pages, with two already indexed under HTTPS. You still didn't clarify if you have an SSL or not, but if you don't and the cost is an issue, look into using a CDN like CloudFlare which provides them for free.